# FB4Linux + Spark

Tags: eclipse, apache-flex

Im trying to build flash player from sources. It written with Flex + MX + Spark. On my Kubuntu 13.04 I:

1. install Eclipse from eclipse.org/downloads (one for building Java + DSL).
2. add FB4Linux to eclipse
3. append Flex SDK 4.5.1A to Flex SDKs list in eclipse
4. create new Flex Project in eclipse
5. copy `src` folder from zip with sources to project folder in workspace
6. refresh project in eclipse
7. fix some errors - fix some `.as` file includes in code (filename mismatch that summon errors on case-sensitive filesystems): file `FooBar.as` was included as `Foobar.as`

On 1-3 I tried some variants like using `eclipse` from repository, `sudo aptitide install eclipse eclipse-jdt eclipse-...` and running eclipse under wine, but all this tryings was ineffective. This list is final (worked) variant.

And now I have 19 errors about Spark. All like this (russian):

```
Стиль "borderAlpha" поддерживается только типом "mx.containers.VBox" с темой (темами) "spark".
```

Which is:

```
Style "borderAlpha" is supported only with type "mx.containers" with theme(s) "spark".
```

In project properties window I have radiobuttons:

- MX + Spark
- Only Spark
- Only MX

Some like described [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7feb.html#WSbde04e3d3e6474c465357b51237cb81d9c-8000). I want to set 1st option, but after clicking `OK` and reopening this project properties window 3rd option always selected. I tried to google compiler (mxmlc?) options that used by FB to identify components list, but unable to found [at mentioned above link](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Flex/4.0/UsingFlashBuilder/WS6f97d7caa66ef6eb1e63e3d11b6c4d0d21-7feb.html#WSbde04e3d3e6474c465357b51237cb81d9c-8000) or on another sites information above this bug.

I am newbie in linux and re-installed some distros few times last 2 months, and on some of them I successfully compile this sources (but they didn't work on site). Today I wanted to deal with this, but I kill my day with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't realize why it helps, but I repeat steps 4-7 - and in new project all goes ok. I create new project `test`, change options to `MX + Spark` and it does reset afterwards. Then I move `src` folder from first project - and option still doesn't reset.